# Colab pip install --upgrade ternsorflow Returns Errors

Tags: tensorflow, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my tensorflow in the Colab to the latest

```
> pip install --upgrade ternsorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ternsorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ternsorflow
```

How can I get the latest version please, then?

CS

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo. Replace ternsorflow by tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

spell check 
ternsorflow >> tensorflow.

Comment: I am sorry! What a silly mistake! I wish Google could guess that!